# IIS 7 URL Redirection

Tags: asp.net, iis, url, redirect

Well, having a small problem.

A 3rd party is connecting to our API, however they are using the wrong URL and the URL no longer exists on our system.  They said the had to revert to some backup code.

Problem is that they have no developer that knows how to fix the code to point to the right URL.

So, my question is how can I take a nonexistant URL in IIS 7 and have redirect to a the correct URL?

URL they are trying to use is (which does not exist):
http://www.mysite.com/page1212.aspx

The URL they  need to hit is:
http://www.mysite.com/page1919.aspx

How can I cause the redirection to happen server side using IIS 7.0 only for this?  I want nothing to change functionally with the website other than this simple redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [IIS URL Rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/).

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008) also a very detailed tutorial on how to use redirecting on IIS7. Scroll a bit down and you'll find what you're looking for.